# Agile Toolkit (ATK4) documentation or tutorial to create a membership site?

Tags: php, atk4

I'd like to get started with testing the ATK4 (Agile Toolkit - http://agiletoolkit.org/). Does anyone have any suggestion regarding where to find a tutorial for using ATK4 with:

- Template development
- User management
- Registration, login, and other account management features

I see potential in the ATK4, but documentation is hard to find, since it's new.

Comment: would this be more relevant to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @martswite Thanks, you're right. As you can tell from my reputation, I'm new to posting on StackOverflow. Can I move it?

Comment: Someone with more rep has to do it. I'm going to assume that because it hasn't been moved that it's maybe ok here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Login and User Management**

You can see some information on changes to /atk4-example/lib/Frontend.php in the [agiletoolkit documentation](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/auth)

Also, i outlined some changes to allow some pages to be public and others only visible while logged on in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376352/atk4-what-is-the-procedure-for-setting-up-an-admin-area/7378882#7378882) which may be helpful

As Romans said, if you look at the Colubris example, you can see examples of using different levels of authorisation e.g. for a client, for a developer and for a manager.

## **Templates**

You can read about [agile toolkit templates here](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/template/how) - the basics are that you define the business logic for each page in a php class. By default, these pages will use the shared.html as a template but you can change this by defining a function in the page class called defaultTemplate.

Templates can use tags to identify where code elements created in the page should be placed such as 
       default content here

Where the data between the tags will be replaced by the components you add in the class defined for that page.  If you dont have default content, you can also use the shorthand version

If you just add elements to a page in the relevant page class ,they will be automatically added to the Content tag.  If you want more control, you can create templates with all the HTML markup you want (or get a graphic designer to do it or even download one you like from a template site like templatemonster.com) and then add tags where you want your page code to be placed.

This is very flexible - you can also add snippets of html code as Views and reuse them multiple times on a page or use the same view in different pages.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out two quite major open-source projects you can look into:

- https://github.com/atk4/atk4-web
- https://github.com/agiletech/colubris

They are very different, however there are many things you can learn from them.

If you are not afraid of beta-documentation, then http://new.agiletoolkit.org/ has frequent updates.

Comment: -D I'm not afraid of beta docs, so I'll check them out. Thanks for the update.