# ATK4 What is the procedure for setting up an Admin Area?

Tags: atk4

I have setup a CRUD area on my frontendAPI.php file (testing my models)... and I even managed to secure it. I would like to do this the proper way... I would like to establish a separate directory/ Page for the Admins. Please advise on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still new at this but I'm trying to do the same for a news page, think i've got the login part working but having problems with the CRUD (will post a question on it shortly) - i have a table to populate with data from an rss feed (but will be manually populated with a CRUD to start with) and then have a page on the front end to pull out the details using views to format each news story.

1. Create a new directory called /page/Admin
2. Create a new file here based on the function e.g. news.php containing

   ```
   class page_admin_news extends Page {
   function init(){
       parent::init();
       $p=$this;

       $crud=$p->add('CRUD');

       $g=$crud->setModel('News');
       if($crud->grid)
              $crud->grid->addPaginator(30);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In Frontend.php, you need to enable the login - for an admin only access, the BasicAuth may be sufficient but there are also classes to use a database to obtain username and password infromation e.g. for a membership site - heres the basic one.
        // If you wish to restrict access to your pages, use BasicAuth class
       $auth=$this->add('BasicAuth')
        ->allow('demo','demo')
        ;
4. You need to modify Frontend.php to enable pages that can be viewed
   without being logged in

   ```
   $auth->allowPage('index');
   $auth->allowPage('news');
   $auth->allowPage('links');
   $auth->allowPage('About');
   if (!$auth->isPageAllowed($this->api->page))
   {
      $auth->check();
   }
   ```
5. And also in Frontend.php, you need to create a different menu if logged in. Note the login and logout pages dont actually exist.

   ```
   if ($auth->isLoggedIn())
   {
     $this->add('Menu',null,'Menu')
       ->addMenuitem('News','admin_news')
       ->addMenuitem('logout')
     ;
   } else {
     $this->add('Menu',null,'Menu')
       ->addMenuitem('News','news')
       ->addMenuitem('Links','links')
       ->addMenuItem('About')
       ->addMenuItem('Login')
       ;
   }
   ```
6. When you login, it goes to page/index.php by default so if you want it to redirect to a particular page when you log in so you can add this to page/index.php

   ```
   class page_index extends Page {
   function init(){
     parent::init();
     $p=$this;

     if($this->api->auth->isLoggedIn())
       $this->api->redirect('admin_news');
   ```

Hope that helps.

Trev

Comment: Trevor is suggesting to have an integrated Admin with the same "API". Normally I use separate URL with it's own .htaccess and it's own API for admin and shared Models.

Comment: The CRUD problem that i mentioned in my post seems to be related to the BasicAuth so i have logged issue 18 on github relating to this.  @Romanish, can you provide more detail on how to create a separate api, presumably sharing the same ATK4 install